# We could not find bundle ID '...' in this Google project

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

If I open a Firebase dynamic link in debug mode, it will give me a warning - `We could not find bundle ID '*id*' in this Google project.`. Still, I have this project in the Firebase console itself, it works and **handles** dynamic links OK if installed, and it is being released to AppStore. Also, it works with all the Firebase services needed pretty well (database & auth).

What is this error than, what is the effect of this on the application and how to resolve this?

P.S.: the dynamic link won't navigate to app store if the app is not installed, and on the visual scheme of the dynamic link debug view the only option that's shown for iOS is `Web Link`, meaning that it will only open the link in the browser. Can these symptoms be connected?

Comment: what's your debug link format?

Comment: @dev.for.fun `*link*?d=1`. But the problem is solved already. I'll post the solution shortly

Comment: that's good to hear @Andrey Ilyunin... looking forward to the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was quite silly: I had a syntax error in the bundle ID inside the link's `ibi` parameter. It had an unseen and unexpected extra "s" character inside. So this warning actually says that project with bundle ID that was specified as the `ibi` parameter was not found in Firebase.